# Getting a SQL Server Error: 258 when connecting via a VPN

Tags: sql, vpn

We have an application that runs fine within[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdQfe.png) our network. When trying to access it via a VPN we get the attached - any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use ip address or domain name to connect (try ip and later on resolve dns issues)? What authentication mode do you use, integrated or mixed (try mixed and later on talk to your sysadmin about blocked ports)?

Comment: Hi, the application is fired up via an executable so not sure what it is calling etc. The error I got was when I tried to check the ODBC (SQL Native Client)